# Get screenshot of a page WITHOUT using selenium webdrivers

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm building an API, which has a feature that consists in scraping the content of Recipe pages. The problem comes when I want to get the full content of some of these pages such as https://www.tudiscovery.com/foodnetwork/recetas/ensalada-de-cuscus-israeli-y-rucula, that is dynamically rendered. I don't want to use Selenium, because I don't want to have external webdrivers installed.

I tried

```
req = Request("https://www.tudiscovery.com/foodnetwork/tiffani-te-invita/recetas/pollo-asado-con-glaseado-de-naranja")
html_page = urlopen(req)
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: You are not going to accomplish this without the webdrivers, sorry. To scrape a dynamically rendered page you need to have a "browser" executing javascript and making additional requests. The webdriver is your browser in this case.

Comment: Got it, thank you